# Firefox, selenium returning invalid proxy?

Tags: python, selenium

when attempting to use a proxy with selenium it is returning the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tronio.py", line 1456, in <module>
    task1()
  File "tronio.py", line 74, in task1
    driver1 = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=desired_capability)
  File "C:\Users\ninja_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 158, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "C:\Users\ninja_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 154, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\ninja_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 243, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\ninja_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\ninja_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 237, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: Invalid proxy configuration entry: httpProxyPort
```

My code is:

```
proxy = ip:port
hostport = proxy[proxy.find("@")+1:]
host = hostport[0:hostport.find(":")]
port = hostport[hostport.find(":")+1:]

if proxy:
  desired_capability = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
  desired_capability['proxy']={
            "httpProxy":host,
            "httpProxyPort": port
            }        

driver1 = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=desired_capability)
```

Help is appreciated, followed another tutorial on stack the proxy is valid I have tested it.

Answer (score 2):

```
PROXY = getProxy()
if PROXY:
    webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX['proxy']={
        "httpProxy":PROXY,
        "ftpProxy":PROXY,
        "sslProxy":PROXY,
        "proxyType":"MANUAL"
    }

driver1 = webdriver.Firefox()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver1, 1000000)
```

This worked for me and is a lot better imo

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well: including the port in the proxy string (without the scheme) worked.